# An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, zsh

> An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

I have already installed json in my computer

```
Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0-static/json-1.8.2/gem_make.out
```

this has drove me crazy can anyone help ?

Comment: Could you add the context of your error? What are you doing?

Comment: @Зелёный    
I am doing bundle install to run my RoR app

Comment: run `ruby -v` and post your result please

Comment: the results is `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]`

Comment: Yeah, what are the errors?

Answer (score 1):

ruby 2.4 is incompatible with that version of json, moveit to 1.8.5

```
bundle install json -v '1.8.5'
```